# Is it possible to start append mode with a command in Vim?

Tags: comments, vim

I am trying to edit a stript in Vim that appends a comment to the end of the line then puts the cursor at the end of the line and sets it to `insert` mode. However, I noticed that
the comment placed at the end of the line has a space after it (e.g. if the comment styles in a particular language were `//` and `/* */`, then the text appended to the end of the line would be `"// "` or `"/* */"`. In the `.vim` plugin, the command `startinsert` is used. However, this places the cursor *before* the space, rather than after. So rather than a comment being generated
like this:

```
// This comment is prepended with a space!
/* This is a great commment! */
```

It ends up looking like this (note the trailing space):

```
//This comment is poorly formatted 
/*So is this one.*/
```

In Vim, is there any command equivalent to '`startappend`', which will place the user into little-`a` append mode rather than insert mode? This way, the user doesn't need to use the right arrow key every time they generate an end-of-line comment with this script.

If this function doesn't exist, how would one go about creating this function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically append mode is a normal mode, the difference is that the cursor is moved first before entering the insert mode. Try moving the cursor to the right after you call `startinsert`:

```
call cursor( line('.'), col('.') + 1)
```

Comment: Just to make this more streamline, according to the documentation instead of `line('.')`, the number `0` can be used instead (just read that).

Answer (score 3):

Just add a `!` to the `:startinsert` command; this will append.

> ```
>       Works like typing "i" in Normal mode.  When the ! is
>       included it works like "A", append to the line.
>       Otherwise insertion starts at the cursor position.
> ```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to specify (just added the edit), that small `a` append mode is necessary, not big `A` in case a multi-line comment is used. For one-line comments, this would work better, though.